@ts-ignore doesn't seem to work for deprecated property warnings
I'm trying to ignore a deprecated property warning in TypeScript, and @ts-ignore doesn't seem to work.
You can reproduce this in TS v5.5.4 like so:
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    // @ts-ignore: This doesn't work, the warning is still shown. :(
    console.log(e.keyCode);

    if (false) {
        // @ts-ignore: This one works, the warning is hidden.
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

Playground
Keycode is deprecated, so the first console.log line shows the warning:
'keyCode' is deprecated.(6385)
lib.dom.d.ts(14645, 8): The declaration was marked as deprecated here

I expect the // @ts-ignore comment to make the warning go away. @ts-ignore does seem to work for other warnings, like the unreachable code one in the second console.log line.
Is there some other comment type I should be using?

It's just a warning, it's still transpiled with or without @ts-ignore.

Yeah, I just don't want the deprecation warning (the strike through of keycode and the warning popup) to show up in my IDE, if possible.

TS doesn't let you do this.  Right now it would be an IDE feature more than a TypeScript feature (at least until TypeScript has the concept of warning-vs-error, as per ms/TS#13408). I could imagine someone filing this as a feature request in GitHub.

@jcalz Weirdly, disabling ts for the entire fail with // @ts-nocheck makes the warning go away. But ts-ignore doesn't work on just the line :-(

The deprecation warning is not a TypeScript error. In TypeScript playground, you can navigate to the "Errors" tab and you will see that there is no error reported. Also your build will never fail because of a deprecation warning. You cannot silence this warning - you can only fix the root cause of the deprecation.
In this particular case, just replace keyCode with code or key, depending on your needs. Note that those properties work differently, so if you are dealing with existing code you will need to adjust it.

Ah, so there's no way to silence the warning? Bummer. In this case, I want to support old versions of IE, so I'll just train myself to ignore the warning in the IDE. Thanks!

A moment of silence for everyone who still needs to support IE in 2024.

In my case I need to use document.execCommand. Weirdly, disabling ts for the entire fail with // @ts-nocheck makes the warning go away. But ts-ignore doesn't work on just the line :-(
